# New answers aren't likely to get reviewed

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

When a question already has several answers with good scores, it seems that posting a new answer might go unnoticed, and therefor not scored.

I get the feeling that posting a new answer to a question with more than 6 answers with scores of 4 or more is useless. No one is going to notice / score it.

Can new answers be "bumped up" somehow to increase their chance to get viewed?

Comment: Besides from putting them on the top of the list on the front page?

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12544/how-to-get-new-answers-to-old-popular-questions-read-voted-on) related question on the Stack Exchange-wide meta.

Answer (score 5):

> Can new answers be "bumped up" somehow to increase their chance to get viewed?

This already happens -- every new answer pushes a question to the top of the stack on the homepage.

Therefore, new answers do tend to get attention, unless the question has a very large (20+) number of answers already.

Even in the case of posting a new answer to a large and perhaps even "accepted" question, experienced users know that you can **click the date field on the question to jump directly to the latest update (answer or edit) in the question**.

[image: click to see latest in question list]

And within the question itself:

[image: click to see latest on question]

Answer (score 3):

Generally, by the time questions get to that point, they've already been answered by other users. I've seen quite a few people lately adding new answers to questions and their answers being much less informative than the already rated ones. I think newer users should focus their effort on new questions instead of reinventing the wheel with old ones.

Comment: Honestly, I think older questions should be locked against new answers. People keep adding new answers and bumping the question up and new questions that /need/ answers are being buried.

Comment: if you think a question should be protected, then flag it for moderator attention: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/

Comment: @Jeff Protecting isn't exactly what I was thinking of. I don't have any problem with people commenting or rating answers they like. But I don't think it's helpful to anyone for newish users to answer questions that were answered months ago.

Comment: it can be, so long as they are getting something out of it, and the answer addresses the question. Good writing is good writing! Also see my answer to this question as well.

Comment: @RalphGallagher, sometimes new information comes along, or a new participant actually does have something new and relevant to say.  Many late answers are low quality, but the community can take care of that.  Let's not prevent the ones that are good from ever getting posted.

Answer (score 1):

I have only asked three questions but on those even after I have "accepted" an answer I still receive notifications of new answers.

In all cases the answers given after I have accepted one of those available after my "waiting period" (about a week) have genuinely added little or nothing to the topic. I am particularly fussy because I try to state why it is I have accepted an answer. If an answer of such amazing depth and insight were to be added that it blew the current best out of the water I would change where the tick got placed and say why.

I think people might view the green tick as a "done deal" and move on. I have to say that doesn't match up to my experience where I read every answer on a question I'm interested in and upvote those answers I feel are adding something new or of significant value.

On a Q where than can be a right A obviously there is little point coming late to the party. However, in Writers.SE there is only best and a new best could happen at any time.

But that's just the way I view it.

Answer (score -5):

Answer to this question would be "No. There is no way of bumping the new answers".